# How to Make a Mac Application With Mono

Tags: c#, windows, macos, mono

so I recently installed Mono on my Windows 10 computer, and I've gotten it to make `.exe` files just fine with a C# program. However, an exe won't run on Mac without a 3rd party program. So I'm wondering, how can I export this as a Mac application instead of a Windows application?

Comment: Note that .NET Core is the current cross-platform technology

Comment: Install Mono on the Mac, and create your executables there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey And what if I don't have access to a Mac?

Comment: Then how are you going to test the executable?  Are you going to trust that it always does the right thing on a Mac?  Case in point: you forget to use `Path.Combine`, and concatenate your path strings instead.  You give it to your mac users and it falls over because path separators are forward slashes on the Mac, not the reverse slashes that are used on Windows.

Comment: Mac apps should be created from Xamarin.Mac in Visual Studio for Mac. Though console apps can run following the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the following in the terminal (on your Mac with Mono installed):

```
mono yourfile.exe
```

**Further Reading**
[Guide:Running Mono Applications](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/)